# Unicode sequence resulting in multiple symbols

Tags: html, unicode

I am making a picklist of emoji, but some unicode sequences (whenever gender is concerned) result in two symbols, instead of one.

For example number 987 of the [Unicode list](http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html): & #x1F3CC;& #x1F3FB;& #x200D;& #x2640;& #xFE0F; (without the spaces) results in a golfer and a female symbol. Is it possible to enter HTML code that renders the same single symbol as shown in the Unicode list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meanwhile I discovered that this has to do with font-family and browser differences. When you copy a symbol from the unicode list in Google Chrome, the pasted HTML code contains a span with a style attribute. With Microsoft Egde, the span element is not present.